# Adicionar Objeto em JCombobox

Tags: java, jcombobox

Estou tentando adicionar um objeto no jCombo box, mas, está dizendo mostrando a mensagem de que o Objeto não pode ser convertido para String, sendo que estou usando o `public String toString()`

Segue o código da Model:

```
public class Model(){
  private int codigo;
  private String nome;
  public int getCodigo(){ return this.codigo; }
  public void setCodigo(int codigo){ this.codigo = codigo; }
  public String getNome(){ return this.nome; }
  public void setNome(String nome){ this.nome = nome; }
  @Override
  public String toString(){ return nome; }
}
```

Do DAO:

```
public class Model_DAO {
     public List<Model> getListModel(){
            List lista = new ArrayList();
            connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            sql = "SELECT id, nome FROM model ";
            try {
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                while( rs.next() ){
                   Model model = new Model();
                   model.setId( rs.getInt( "id" ) );
                   model.setNome( rs.getString("nome") );
                   lista.add( model );
                }
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EnergiaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return lista;
        }
}
```

Preenchimento do Combobox

```
public class TelaClasse {
    public TelaClasse(){
      popularComboMedidor();
      JFrame tela = new JFrame();
      tela.add( jc_model );
    }
    JCombobox jC_model = new JComboBox(); 

    private void popularComboMedidor(){

            Model_DAO md = new Model_DAO();
            List lista = md.getListModel();
            Iterator it = lista.iterator();
            jC_model.removeAllItems(); //JC jCombobox        
            while( it.hasNext() ){
              Model model = (Model) it.next();
              //  System.out.println(model);
              jC_model.addItem( model );
            }
        }
   }
```

Lembrando que eu sempre fiz assim, nesse outro  computador que estou usando não está funcionando. O método `toString()` só está funcionando com `System.out.println()`

Comment: Isso já foi respondido aqui, da uma olhada nas duas respostas da pergunta marcada, uma das duas será a solução, com certeza.

Comment: Pois é, eu adicionei o método `toString()` e não funcionou ainda

Comment: Tem duas respostas la, veja as duas. Se nenhuma servir, voce precisa fornecer **[mcve]** porque esse codigo ai nem é executavel, portanto, nao da pra saber a origem do erro.

Comment: Exatamente, ele não mostra erro. Os principais métodos eu coloquei. Pode me sugerir o que mais falta? Porque se fosse em web eu usaria aquela ferramenta do proprio stackoverflow para mostrar

Comment: Acessa o link que mandei, nele explica direitinho como elaborar um mcve.

Comment: Seu Model não está usando `toString` e sim `getString`. Não é esse o método correto pra sobrescrever.

Comment: Verdade, digitei errado, mas já corrigi

Comment: Olha, pelo que to vendo sua pergunta continua duplicata, a solução do diego augusto soluciona seu problema. jcombobox não pode receber Model porque ele não conhece essa classe. Voce terá que fazer com que seja conhecida para ele, e isso so é possivel criando uma AbstractListmodel.

Comment: Como lhe falei, eu já usei desse modo inúmeras vezes, mas justamente hoje não funcionou. Seu método é bem mais simples

Comment: Mas não servirá da forma como você está fazendo, se não quer fazer do modo simples, você não pode passar Model pro combobox, pelos motivos já explicados.

Comment: Na verdade eu prefiro fazer  do modo como fez respondeu lá, que é o padrão que sempre usei, mas .... não sei o que houve

Comment: Eu já expliquei o que houve 2 vezes, por favor, releia meus comentários anteriores.